# Shared Hosting with services

Tags: asp.net, windows-services, shared-hosting

I was curious if there is a shared hosting platform for asp.net web sites that would allow me to setup a service that would do something at predetermined intervals. Dedicated hosting is not an option due to budget constraints.

So far, it looks like my solution will have to be to set an object in the cache and use the expired callback.

Has any one used the above method? and how successful was it?

Is there a better option or method than this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If setting up a windows service in not an option you can start a background thread in the global.asax Application_Start

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a few different options, but this seems to be the best option.